# Set Firestore Rules for only Anonymous Login

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to allow read and write to my Firestore database for only users logged in anonymously.

This is the logic I am using

```
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously()
  .then(() => {
    // Signed in.
    console.log("we are signed in")

  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    var uid = user.uid;
    console.log(user.uid + " User uid")
  } else {}
});
```

This is the rule I have setup but its not working.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider == "anonymous";
```

You can read more about `request.auth` in [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth)

Comment: Just tried that but I am getting code 403 - PERMISSION_DENIED so I am wondering if my code is wrong somewhere

Comment: Where is your query?

Comment: My Query is simply - GET https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject/databases/(default)/documents/users. which I have is a function. I think I need to check somehow if an annonymous user is logged in them perform the GET but not quite sure

Comment: How do you get the ID Token of user? are you sure it is coming from anonymous ayuth @IanBarber ?

Comment: I am not 100% sure. What is the best way to check that please @dharmaraji

Comment: @IanBarber log your ID token and then paste it [here](https://www.jstoolset.com/jwt) then look for `sign_in_provider`. What does it say?

Comment: auth.currentUser.uid  gives me  "lSw6BkmaN0MjWtMPZKZXgqSpMMV2" but the jwt page returns Bad token. Expected format is three segments separated by periods, i.e. <header>.<payload>.<signature>

Comment: @IanBarber not the UID, log token. `await aut.curretnUser.getIdToken()`

Comment: {"header": {"alg":"RS256","kid":"7b87112375427d657f5e25ca01d565e592a231db","typ":"JWT"}, "payload": {"iss":"https://securetoken.google.com/digital-zone-system","aud":"digital-zone-system","auth_time":1632747985,"user_id":"lSw6BkmaN0MjWtMPZKZXgqSpMMV2","sub":"lSw6BkmaN0MjWtMPZKZXgqSpMMV2","iat":1632747985,"exp":1632751585,"email":"mario@gmail.com","email_verified":false,"firebase":{"identities":{"email":["mario@gmail.com"]},"sign_in_provider":"password"}}}

Comment: @IanBarber you seem to be logged in with email and password and not anonymous..

Comment: will these rules work for the above.  service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}

Comment: @IanBarber because that allow any logged in user to access the resource. You only want anonymous users to access it ?